# cout float without trailing zeros and with only 3 digits after the

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print a `float` variable, I want it to have only 3 digits. However, if they are zeros, they do not end up printing.

For example

```
1.230 -> should be out like this 1.23
1.456432 -> 1.456
1.4000006 -> 1.4
```

currently I'm using

```
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(3) <<res2<<endl;
```

and its still shows more zeros, like 0.010 but it should be 0.01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't want to do any kind of rounding. I think this function will do what you want:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string remove_trailing_zeros(float num, int precision)
{
    const int maxPrecision(6);
    if (precision > maxPrecision) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("precision too much for float!");
    }

    std::string str = std::to_string(num);    //convert to string
    str.erase(str.find('.') + precision + 1); //chop to precision
    str.erase(str.find_last_not_of('0') + 1, std::string::npos ); //erase any trailing zeroes
    if (str.back() == '.')  //remove remaining dot if necessary
        str.pop_back();

    return str;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<float> numbers = { 0.3, 1, 1.456432, 1.4010006, 1.0 };

    for (auto n : numbers) {
        std::cout << remove_trailing_zeros(n, 3) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0.3
1
1.456
1.401
1
```

Be careful you don't exceed a precision of 6 for floats because that's the default number of decimal numbers a float converted to string contains.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it would be parsing it to a string using `stringstream` and remove the trailing zero manually. <strike>with [string::find_last_not_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_not_of/).</strike> Edit: as @Eljay pointed out, `find_last_not_of` wouldn't work on cases like `1010` or `120`. Instead, the following code simply keeps removing the last `0` or `.` if a floating-point exists.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "iomanip"
#include "vector"

using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::setprecision;
using std::fixed;
using std::stringstream;
using std::vector;

string removeTrailingZeros(float number) {
  stringstream stream;
  stream << fixed << setprecision(3) << number;
  string floatStr = stream.str();
  while (floatStr.find('.') != string::npos && floatStr.back() == '0' || floatStr.back() == '.')
    floatStr.pop_back();
  return floatStr;
}

int main() {
  vector<float> numbers = {
    1010,   
    120, 
    1.50005, 
    0.004, 
    1.9994, 
    1.9996,
    2.4321, 
    0,   
    -1.5,    
    0.69,  
    0.1,
    1.007
  };
  for (auto n : numbers) {
    cout << fixed << setprecision(3) << n << ": " << removeTrailingZeros(n) << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1010.000: 1010
120.000: 120
1.500: 1.5
0.004: 0.004
1.999: 1.999
2.000: 2
2.432: 2.432
0.000: 0
-1.500: -1.5
0.690: 0.69
0.100: 0.1
1.007: 1.007
```

Comment: The number `1010.0f` doesn't survive well.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks for pointing it out, I modified my answer with a different approach. I'm not sure if there is a neater way of doing it.

Comment: I used your code
but when I give it  0.0158730168
it gives back 0.016 instead of 0.015